# Acer Aspire Laptop E5-475-37MN where to find bios utility files to flash bios

Tags: windows-10, bios, acer-aspire, black-screen-of-death

When I turn on my laptop the only thing that works properly are the LED lights and the fan, it displays a black screen.

I was thinking of flashing the bios using a usb drive with BIOS update utility inside but when I go to the acer website to download and extract the BIOS_ACER_1.21.zip in my dell laptop I only have the readme file and an insyde application in the extracted folder.

I ran the insyde application on my dell laptop but I wasnt able to obtain anything.... Am I right to assume that the insyde application only works if I run it in my acer laptop? Please help me I'm so noob at this :(

Answer (score 1):

In the nicest possible way, you should not be trying to do this yourself. I know a lot of professionals that have been working with computers for 30+ years and they still second guess themselves when they flash a bios.

Your best course of action would be to take this to a computer shop and ask them to take a look. If you only see a black screen, it is also unlikely that you will be able to get to the Bios to actually perform a bios update in any case.

Answer (score 0):

have you reset the BIOS yet? That means removing the power supply, removing the battery, disconnecting the bios battery and then holding the power button down for about 30 seconds to drain the remaining power? Then put everything back together and start, what happens then?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm sorry. I will always try to translate into English

Comment: Your answer isn't a answer it is a comment. But of course you can not comment at this stage. Please note this is an old question. See [answer] make some more reputation points and see how Superuser works...